# JXbrowser initialization fails when run in empty folder: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:...jxbrowser-browser.log.lck

Tags: javafx, jxbrowser

OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.3 (16D32)

jxbrowser version: 6.14.2

I set jxbrowser cache and logs directory to the single folder near the executed jar file. When it run from scratch an exception rises: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException:...jxbrowser-browser.log.lck

If run the previous version (6.3) and after that the current one, then everything works correct.

```
[DEBUG] 2017-07-30 15:55:00.411 [main] ScalarSelectOperation - select from result set
Exception in Application init method
java.lang.RuntimeException: Exception in Application init method
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:912)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$155(LauncherImpl.java:182)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /%PATH_TO_JAR_FOLDER%/.cache/jxbrowser-browser.log.lck
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.translateToIOException(UnixException.java:86)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:102)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixException.rethrowAsIOException(UnixException.java:107)
    at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.newFileChannel(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:177)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:287)
    at java.nio.channels.FileChannel.open(FileChannel.java:335)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(FileHandler.java:459)
    at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(FileHandler.java:292)
    at ru.mybetter.ui.desktop.BetterClient.redirectLogMessagesToFile(BetterClient.java:174)
    at ru.mybetter.ui.desktop.BetterClient.init(BetterClient.java:106)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:841)
    ... 2 more

2017-07-30 15:55:00,610 pool-2-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=2a139a55, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@f5a3839]
2017-07-30 15:55:00,611 pool-2-thread-1 DEBUG Stopping LoggerContext[name=2a139a55, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@f5a3839]...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the exception stack trace the error comes from:

```
ru.mybetter.ui.desktop.BetterClient.redirectLogMessagesToFile(BetterClient.java:174)
```

I suppose you create `FileHandler` instance with an invalid path to the file that doesn't exist. Or, according to Javadoc of the `FileHandler(String pattern)` the `IOException` can be thrown from its constructor when `there are IO problems opening the files`.

Please make sure that the path to the file you pass to the `FileHandler` constructor is accessible from your Java program and there are no read/write permission issues with it.

Comment: Thank you, Vladimir! The mistake was in directory with logs, in special cases it doesn't exist.